# How could I set MAILER_DSN param in php code?

Tags: php, environment-variables, symfony5

I need to set the MAILER_DSN variable with values that I have to take from the database. How can i do this? How can you override a .env file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know if Symfony has a Workaround for this, but I would do it that way

1. Create a Event Listen for the first Kernel Event.
2. In this Event override the $_SERVER["MAILER_DSN"]

You can try it and give us a Feedback if it works for you.

Or you try to make your [own EnvProcessor](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/env_var_processors.html#custom-environment-variable-processors), that gets die Information from the Database.

Comment: ENV Processor. Try once - works good, but is I update cjnfig it return old value, may be you know how could I flush old values?

Comment: what you mean with old value?